# Android ProgressDialog doesn't show in onCreate using Thread

Tags: android, multithreading, thread-safety, progressdialog

I want to load some contacts when an activity is created. Because this is a long running operation I want to notify the user through a ProgressDialog. A request for this app is to not use AsyncTasks so I'm using threads but the progress is not showing. This is my onCreate method:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_contacts);
    handler = new Handler();

    mActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    mActionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progress.setMessage("Loading Contacts ");
    progress.setIndeterminate(true);
    progress.show();

    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            contacts = ContactsUtils.getContacts(getContentResolver());
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    progress.dismiss();
                    // UpdateDisplay();
                };
            });
        }

    });

    t.start();
    try {
        t.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Log.e("Interrupted Exception:", e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }

    // other methods

}
```

Am I missing something? Thanks

**SOLVED:** The rest of the code from onCreate, after the join, should be moved to a Handler, and join should be removed

Comment: I see you create PD where are you displaying it ?

Comment: where do you call `show()`?

Comment: also you are better off using a asynctask

Comment: I am curious. Why would you not use AsyncTask?

Comment: I have to do it both ways. With async task it's working but I can't figure why it's not working with Thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missig

```
progress.show()
```

plus why you are using threads don't you think async tasks will do this task with beauty?

The issue you don't see your progress dialog is because

```
try {
    t.join();
 } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      Log.e("Interrupted Exception:", e.getLocalizedMessage());
 }
```

this hold main thread till your task is done, just comment it

Comment: I forgot to paste it here. The task request specifies that I'm not allowed to use async tasks

Comment: @mawus why should you not use asynctasks?

Comment: I have to make my UI thread to wait for the thread to execute, otherwise I'll have no contacts in my list

Comment: Progress dialog wont be displayed unless you let UI thread idle. You can always stop user cancelling dialog  by setting  `pd.setCancelable(false);`

Comment: You were right, I've removed join, and used a handler for executing the rest of my code from onCreate. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
Try This Code:-


@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.launching);


        final ProgressDialog myPd_ring=ProgressDialog.show(Launching.this, "", "Loading please wait..", true);
        myPd_ring.setCancelable(true);
        new Thread(new Runnable() {  
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                }catch(Exception e){}
                Intent intt=new Intent();
                intt.setClass(Launching.this, MainController.class);
                startActivity(intt);
                finish();
                myPd_ring.dismiss();
            }
        }).start();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you're trying to do something with the UI from a background thread, either use a `Handler` or call it within `runOnUiThread(Runnable())`

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
private ProgressDialog pDialog; // global
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_launcher);
    color_list = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.color_list);
    imageView1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.icon);
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Launcher.this);
    pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);

            showProgressDialog();

Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

@Override
public void run() {
    contacts = ContactsUtils.getContacts(getContentResolver());
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            hideProgressDialog();
        };
    });
 }

});
}


private void showProgressDialog() {
    if (!pDialog.isShowing())
        pDialog.show();
}

private void hideProgressDialog() {
    if (pDialog.isShowing())
        pDialog.hide();
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your question

Comment: i am saying with your code progress bar is showing on screen or not?

Comment: no, but progress.isShowed() return true ... I thing it's related with that join, as @nizammoidu said

Comment: I need to make my UI thread to wait for thread execution, in order to load data, that's why I used join